# How to test private method passed in the supplier method of CompletableFuture.supplyAsync method?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test, completable-future

I want to write JUnit test for a public method which uses `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` to process some data and then save it to the DB. However, the supplier method passed contains a private method which contains the main logic of processing and saving data into the DB. I want to test this private method as well in the process of testing the parent public method. I am clueless how to proceed.

Here is the sample code:

```java
public void updateGrowthOverviewData(int startId, int endId){
        int limit = 10;
        int currentStartId = startId;
        List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (currentStartId <= endId) {
            long currentEndId = currentStartId + limit - 1;
            long finalCurrentStartId = currentStartId;
            futureList.add(this.getFuture(() -> {
                try {
                    return processGrowthOverviewData(finalCurrentStartId, currentEndId);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.error("Exception in updateGrowthOverviewData | while fetching data for updateGrowthOverviewData | startId : {}, endId : {} | Exception: {}", finalCurrentStartId, currentEndId, ex.getStackTrace());
                    return false;
                }
            }));
            currentStartId += limit;
        }
        
        futureList.forEach(obj -> {
            try {
                log.info("in updateGrowthOverviewData| value: {}", obj.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                log.error("Exception | in updateGrowthOverviewData | while fetching data from Future Object | Exception {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
            }
        });
    }
    
    private Boolean processGrowthOverviewData(int startId, int endId){
        // code for processing data and saving it into the db -> includes several other private methods -> for better code readability
        return true;
    }

private <T> CompletableFuture<T> getFuture(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, this.serviceExecutor);
    }
```

I don't want to mock `this.getFuture()` by making it a protected method, as I won't be able to test the private methods created for better code readability. Kindly help me how to test the method `updateGrowthOverviewData`. I am new to writing UTs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your UTs should only be written against your public methods.  If those public methods then call into a private method, you'll get coverage on your private methods as well.  Consider this code as an example, I have a method that subtracts a lesser number from the greater.  It calls a private method to determine the proper order for the operands.

```
public int subtractFromGreaterOfTwo(int left, int right) {
  if (gt(left, right)) {
    return left - right;
  } else {
    return right - left;
  }
}

private boolean gt(int left, int right) {
  return left > right;
}
```

We don't test the private method directly, but instead we write test cases that will cover the conditions of the private method.  There are three possible conditions here; left > right, right > left, left == right.  The first condition will return true, the latter two will return false.

Both of these methods will be covered by a single test that would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void testLeftGreater() {
    assertThat(someService.subtractFromGreaterOfTwo(10, 5), is(equalTo(5)));
    assertThat(someService.subtractFromGreaterOfTwo(5, 10), is(equalTo(5)));
    assertThat(someService.subtractFromGreaterOfTwo(10, 10), is(equalTo(0)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lane. I understand that. But the problem I am facing is how should I consider CompletableFuture.supplyAsync in this process in my case. Can you suggest something based on the code sample I have shared.